# method invoked or method called?

Tags: methods, terminology, invoke

I am not sure if this question is relevant but I see the expression "the method is invoked" a lot , So Is there a technical difference between invoking a method or calling a method or It's just other word for the same action ?

P.S : Clearly , I am not an English native speaker and looking for invoke definition on the web didn't help .

Comment: Another word for same action...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Invoking" a method and "calling" a method are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't typically a technical difference.

If I were to describe my own usage of the terms, I suppose I would reserve "invocation" for the subset of method calls where there is no value being returned or the value returned is (or can be) ignored.  In other words I typically wouldn't say I'm invoking a *function*.

For instance, I would sooner say that "method A *invokes* `Thread.start()`" than "method B *invokes* `toString()`".  Invoke has the connotation of starting an action.  But I would say that I *call* either of them.